# What exactly is a "Console"?

Tags: c#, windows

I am trying to writing a console application. It has its original console, let's name it console A. And I want this application to do the following things via C#:

> 1. Open another console B in another thread, then get input from A and output it to B;
> 2. type a command in A, such as dir, and show the output in B;

while doing the above things (still not done yet. X_X ), I find myself lack a through understanding of *what a console window is*, and *how it is assigned to a console application*, especially *the very first console when my console application starts to run*. Could some one shed some light on me?

Is *console window* physically a memory area in the video memory? Or something else?
Could different threads within the same process have different console of its own for its own I/O?

Many thanks.

Now I am using one console application to start another console application in a new process. Thus I can have 2 consoles output at the same time.

---

My understanding now is that, for Windows OS, a console is a special window, and it's a system resource that OS assigned to the application without-a-UI as a necessary user interface. Windows OS handles the wiring between the system-prepared console window with our UI-less application.

Comment: The console is the part of the computer that has the lights and switches on it, and maybe a paper tape reader, on the more expensive models.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Windows terms, a Console is a textual GUI window that you see when you run "cmd.exe". It allows you to write text to, and read text from, a window without the window having any other UI chrome such as toolbars, menus, tabs, etc,..

To get started you'll want to load Visual Studio, create a new project and choose "Console Application". Change the boilerplate code that Visual Studio produces to:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace MyConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Hello, world!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

When you run your application, a console window will open with the text "Hello, world!" and it'll stay open until you press a key. That is a console application.

> Is console window physically a memory area in the video memory? Or something else?

It's not physically a memory area in video memory, it's "something else". The Wikipedia [Win32 console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_console) page gives a fairly robust descrption of the ins and outs.

Comment: "is a textual GUI" ummmm.... isn't a GUI (Graphical User Interface) meant to be graphical, so a console isn't a GUI at all (completely lacks graphics, discounting ASCII art of course). That was the entire point of distinguishing something as having a GUI, it didn't have a purely ASCII based interface.

Comment: Console is typically referred to as CLI (command line interface) or CLUI (command line user interface)

Comment: @Grant, maybe "textual UI window" may have been a better way of putting it. My fingers stuck the G in there without me even thinking about it, or realising! =)

Comment: Hmm, my preferred book on SO (Tanenbaum) calls this a **shell**. I *think* a console is a shell executing from inside a GUI.

Comment: @Bruno - Yes, console programs will usually run in a shell when you are using a GUI based OS. A shell is just a different operating _environment_ meant to provide support for the application that usually isn't available in the host OS (in this case it provides a command line with stdin/stdout as well as a few other dos like features).

Comment: My understanding now is that, for Windows OS, a console is a special window, and it's a system resource that OS assigned to the application without-a-UI as a necessary user interface. Windows OS handles the wiring between the system-prepared console window with our UI-less application.

Comment: @Grant: Thanks... +1, much more complete than what I've told the OP.

Comment: Hmmm.. A console is a CUI or Character User Interface as I remember reading in some old computer book. But today GUI and UI have become almost synonymous being that its so common and everything.

Answer (score 2):

A console application has only one window.  It does not have window management functions in order to spawn child "consoles".

You can start additional console applications, but these are separate entities.

Comment: @Johannes - you should post that as an answer as that seems to be what the OP is after.

Comment: @Johannes Rossel: You can create multiple consoles but your process can only be bound to one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

A windows application can have one console, or no console, it can't have more than one. See the documentation for [AllocConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944(VS.85).aspx).
The console is basically an emulation of the 'pre-Windows' days when there would literally be a 'control console' i.e. a keyboard and screen attached to a mainframe computer.
To do what you want you could spawn another process with its own console and communicate between the two, or make a GUI application which looks like a console window.

Answer (score 1):

No. It's a windows GUI subsystem. In WinAPI there are functions to work with console: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A (OS) console is a process (containg one or more threads of executions, all of them sharing the same memory space), and this process has:

- standard input (a stream of input bytes), what you key in
- standard output (a stream of output bytes), what the program prints
- standard error (a stream of output bytes), what the program prints when it's complaining about something

So if you want to create another console (from .Net) and link the input/outputs I understand you have to create a process (executing "cmd.exe" by example).

I don't know the API of .Net for process manipulation but if it's like Java you can hook up stdin, out and err so you can play with your created process from the original one.